# Basic Javascript calculations with html input

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am making a basic calculator for a game. The user inputs the amount of level 1 wall they have and the program multiplies that by 200 and returns the answer. It is pretty basic but I cant find where I have gone wrong.

```
<form onsubmit="return calcWalls(0);" style="display: inline;">
    <!-- Title of Form /-->
    <font>Level 1</font> 
    <!-- Gets Input /-->
    <input size="10" value="0" id="level1_input_">
    <!-- Calls 'calcWalls' /-->
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcWalls;">
    <!-- Outputs result /-->
    <span id="level1_result_"> = 0 Gold/Elixer</span>
</form>

<script>
    function calcWalls {
        <!-- Gets user input /-->
        var level1 = Number(document.getElementById("level1_input").value);
        <!-- Does calculations /-->
        var level1cost=level1*200;
        <!-- If the input is invalid this handles it /-->
        if (isNaN(level1input)) return ("???");
        if (level1input <= 0) return (0)
        <!-- Outputs result /-->
        document.getElementById("level1_result_").innerHTML = Math.round+(level1cost*100)/100;
                    }
</script>
```

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcWalls;">` Youre not calling a function! Use calcWalls(); instead.

Comment: And you're using HTML comments inside a script. Please change it for // or /* */ when needed.

Comment: Sorry but your code is not well formed! Tidy first and update!

Answer (score -1):

I've got your answer. Please, next time consider using the console (`CTRL + SHIFT + K` in Firefox) for debugging.

JS:

```
calcWalls = function () {
    var level1 = Number(document.getElementById("level1_input_").value);
    var level1cost = level1 * 200;
    if (isNaN(level1cost)) return ("???");
    if (level1cost <= 0) return (0)
    document.getElementById("level1_result_").innerHTML = Math.round(level1cost * 100) / 100;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return calcWalls(0);" style="display: inline;">
    <!-- Title of Form /--> <font>Level 1</font> 
    <!-- Gets Input /-->
    <input size="10" value="0" id="level1_input_">
    <!-- Calls 'calcWalls' /-->
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcWalls();">
    <!-- Outputs result /--> <span id="level1_result_"> = 0 Gold/Elixer</span>

</form>
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1r177khr/)

**EDIT:** What you had wasn't a programming problem, rather a i-am-not-paying-attention-to-details problem. Double check variable names and function declarations next time.

Comment: I'd like it very much for the person that downvoted my answer to explain to me why he/she did it. Thank you.